# Issue with in_degree function

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I've troube using the in_degree function in boost graph. It fails with the following crytic message :

> ..\boost_lib\boost_1_66_0\boost\graph\detail\adjacency_list.hpp|1673|error:
>   no matching function for call to 'in_edge_list(Graph&, void*&)'|

Why is `vb` of `void*&` type?  It is supposed to be a vertex_descriptor.

Here a small example reproducing my issue :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

//The typedef used
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS> graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

int main()
{
    graph g(1);

    boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_iterator vb,ve;
    boost::tie(vb,ve)=boost::vertices(g);
    std::cout << boost::in_degree(*vb,g);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is vb of void*& type? It is supposed to be a vertex_descriptor.

And why shouldn't that descriptor be of `void*` type? That's exactly the type that it's defined to be.

> error: no matching function for call to 'in_edge_list(Graph&, void*&)'

The problem is, there is no matching function call, because `in_degree()` isn't supposed to work on your graph. You can see what  your graph supports here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html

As you can see `in_degree()` requires the `BidirectionalGraph` concept.

You could be satisfied knowing just the out-degree:

```
std::cout << boost::out_degree(*vb, g);
```

Or you can switch to a BidirectionalGraph model:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e796f45f1770de1)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::bidirectionalS> graph;
typedef graph::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

int main() {
    graph g(1);

    boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_iterator vb, ve;
    boost::tie(vb, ve) = boost::vertices(g);

    std::cout << boost::out_degree(*vb, g) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::in_degree(*vb, g) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
0
0
```